# Stop IIS from serving files in virtual directory

Tags: iis-7, virtual-directory

I have a virtual directory (called "File") setup for my web application.  The directory is used to house user file uploads as well as official downloads that we offer.

I want to prevent any file from the "File/UserUpload" directory from ever being served up to a user.  It would be pretty difficult (i.e. it will never happen) for a user to come up with the proper filename to request a file since the files are created with a GUID, but I'd like to disallow it nonetheless.

How can I stop IIS from serving files in the virtual directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a web.config file to the directory which denies all users access to the directory.

It should look something like this:

IIS 7:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
      <authorization>
          <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
      </authorization>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Here is another SO post which may be helpful:
https://serverfault.com/questions/72680/iis7-how-to-block-access-with-a-web-config-file

Comment: This did not work.  I restarted IIS just to be safe, but to no avail.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see that you were using IIS7.  See my edits.